# create AmazonHttpClient in a protected environment which does not allow getEnv calls

Tags: java, aws-sdk, securitymanager, java-security-manager

Switching from version 1.11.700 to 1.11.908 of [AWS SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk) one of our libraries is now unable to work in a protected environment. More specifically the new SDK version has changed [ClientConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#constructor.summary) so that it now instantiates a RetryPolicy by checking env vars.

Unfortunately we're going to deploy this library into an environment which forbids (SecurityManager in place) access to the env vars.
This means that all our code which depends on a [AmazonHttpClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.html#constructor.summary) is not usable anymore because:

- in order to instantiate an `AmazonHttpClient` you must pass in a valid `ClientConfiguration` (null is not accepted)
- in order to create a valid `ClientConfiguration` you need to be able to read env vars

here is the stack trace:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.AWS_RETRY_MODE")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:886)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at com.boomi.security.ExtendedSecurityManager.checkPermissionImpl(ExtendedSecurityManager.java:207)
    at com.boomi.security.ExtendedSecurityManager.checkPermission(ExtendedSecurityManager.java:114)
    at java.lang.System.getenv(System.java:894)
    at com.amazonaws.retry.internal.RetryModeResolver.envVar(RetryModeResolver.java:67)
    at com.amazonaws.retry.internal.RetryModeResolver.resolveRetryMode(RetryModeResolver.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.retry.internal.RetryModeResolver.<init>(RetryModeResolver.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.retry.RetryPolicy.<clinit>(RetryPolicy.java:35)
    at com.amazonaws.retry.PredefinedRetryPolicies.<clinit>(PredefinedRetryPolicies.java:30)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:89)
```

None of the options we come up with does apply to this scenario:

- Subclassing `ClientConfiguration` to suppress exception: cannot try-catch the call to the super() constructor
- `ClientConfiguration` is a class thus we don't have an interface to implement
- `java.policy` cannot be modified to allow access to the property: the environment is not within our control
- exception is being thrown from  rather then from  thus it's not even related to a single object...

Comment: Are you able to at least modify the java policy file?

~/.java.policy` or `[java.home]/lib/security/java.policy` and add the following:

grant {
    permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.AWS_RETRY_MODE", "read";
};

Comment: Thanks but modifying the security environment is not something we can do on that environment, I'll clarify the question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a builder() for AmazonHttpClient, so perhaps IF you set the retryPolicy on the builder, the ClientConfiguration wont look for a retryPolicy.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/AmazonHttpClient.Builder.html

---------------- Another option:

We can see in the official SDK code that ClientConfiguration() constructor can take another ClientConfiguration so create a custom one using extends.

```
   public class ClientConfigurationByPassingSecurity extends ClientConfiguration{
    
        @Override
        public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy(){
           return xx;
        }
    
   }
```

//Create your AmazonHttpClient passing this custom

```
ClientConfiguration customClientConfiguration = new ClientConfigurationByPassingSecurity ();

ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration(customClientConfiguration);


new AmazonHttpClient(clientConfig);
```

Override any method that fails due to getVars.

Comment: Very smart approach! Unfortunately this does not seem to work because unfortunately the custom retry policy is being read _after_ object initialization whereas the AccessControlException is being raised during class initialization (i.e. earlier :-( )

Comment: You are right, @SimoneAvogadro  they are static variables and will be initalized before the constructor.   I looked into it, and the issue starts from RetryPolicy because it is calling RetryModeResolver which first looks at env, system properties, then finally config file.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/2bb86d619fb75ea3e1d0d10b86c1fc2d1a482855/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/retry/internal/RetryModeResolver.java#L71

I saw you opened a bug ticket, good luck